# Failed to compile module not found in React.js

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, tailwind-css

I ran into this problem [image: website] when am following this video tutorial until here: https://youtu.be/nGoSP3MBV2E?list=PLIZkq64ad9C4POK0E1fhCaxlxTXwr7wSh&t=5976.

The problem seem to arised from these 2 files:
[image: error from register/route.js & models/User.js]

Here's the source code of those 2 files:

register/route.js:
'''

```
  import mongoose from "mongoose";

    import {User} from "@/models/User";;

    export async function POST(req){
    const body = await req.json();
    mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL);
    const cretedUser = await User.create(body);
    return Response.json(createdUser);
}
```

'''

Model/User.js:

'''

```
    import {model, models, Schema} from "mongoose";

    const UserSchema = new Schema({
    email:{type:String, required:true, unique: true},
    password:{
        type:String, 
        required: true, 
        validate: pass => {
        if(!pass?.length || pass.length <5 ){
            new Error('password must be at least 5 characters');
        }
    },
    },
    },{timestamps: true}); 

export const User = models?.User || model('User', UserSchema);
```

'''

I have tried correcting any typo as well as fixing any incorrect path but nothing worked so far, here's how my repo look like:[image: Repo]

Comment: Please post the code as a text, and not a screenshot.

Comment: I have fixed the post like you asked. Thanks for telling me

Comment: Your `User.js` file is in `src/app/models/User.js`. Try `@/src/app/models/User.js` as the import path.

Comment: @NihadBadalov I have tried your suggestion by changing it to  `import {User} from "/src/app/models/User.js";` and it worked. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a Next.js app and the `User.js` file is located in `src/app/models/User.js`.

The import should be `import {User} from "@/src/app/models/User.js";`

*Read more about Next.js Path Aliases here: https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/absolute-imports-and-module-aliases*

Answer (score 0):

Simply changing from `@/src/app/models/User.js` to `import {User} from "/src/app/models/User.js";` work for me